# Why does += work on std::map keys that don't have values?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl

I was looking at the way's people solved the problem proposed [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/meeting-rooms-ii/):

> Given an array of meeting time intervals consisting of start and end times [[s1,e1],[s2,e2],...] (si < ei), find the minimum number of conference rooms required.

One of the solutions was to do the following:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::max;
using std::map;
using std::vector;

struct Interval {
  int start;
  int end;
  Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}
  Interval(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) {}
};

int minMeetingRooms(vector<Interval>& intervals) {
    map<int, int> changes;
    for (auto i : intervals) {
      changes[i.start] += 1;
      changes[i.end] -= 1;
    }
    int rooms = 0, maxrooms = 0;
    for (auto change : changes)
      maxrooms = max(maxrooms, rooms += change.second);
    return maxrooms;
}
```

Which increments a counter every time a new meeting starts and decrements a counter every time a meeting ends, taking the max of that counter and the previous max on every iteration.

---

What I'm curious about though is the part where the map is intialized

```
for (auto i : intervals) {
  changes[i.start] += 1;
  changes[i.end] -= 1;
}
```

The values in the map have never been set, but yet you can still use the `+=` operator. I assume this causes the map to create a `0` in that place, which you then increment, but is this undefined behavior? Also is there a default value for every type? For example, if I had a map of `<int, string>` would what it put as the default value? Does it just call the default constructor?

Basically what I'd like to know is the internals of `std::map` which allow for one to add to a key that doesn't yet exists, and how it varies from type to type.

---

As a side note:

If I were trying to write more idiomatic code, I would have put

```
if (changes.find(i.start) == changes.end()) changes[i.start] = 0
if (changes.find(i.end) == changes.end()) changes[i.end] = 0
```

but I'm guessing it's a performance hit or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

The insertion just uses the default constructor for the key, and the default constructor for `int` produces 0.

Your "more idiomatic" code is exactly the opposite of idiomatic. You use `operator[]` when you *want* autovivification, you only use `count`/`find` when you are trying to avoid autovivification.

If you come from a Python background this may seem backwards, but it's idiomatic C++. C++ `std::map` behaves more like a Python `defaultdict` than `dict`; operator lookup auto-vivifies, avoiding autovivification requires explicit method calls.

Comment: Alright thanks! I assumed I was missing something and I'm glad you commented on how my "more idiomatic" idea was wrong in this case. Appreciate it!

Comment: @AR7: Glad it helped. This approach makes much more sense in C++ than it would in Python, since C++ has static types for the value anyway, so it always knows what should be there. Python's dynamic typing means it doesn't have that knowledge normally (the value could be of any type, so autovivifying doesn't make sense).